# How we can get different @ExceptionHandler for different controllers in java spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I have a single class with 2 different controllers. I want to write @ExceptionHandler specific to controller.

For example, for controller 1, only @ExceptionHandler 1 should be called and for controller 2, only @ExceptionHandler 2 should be called.

This might be the silly one but I am new to the java. Please help me on this.

Comment: Simply make ExceptionHandler1 to catch Exception1, ExceptionHanler2 to catch Exception2, then from controller 1 you throw Exception1 and from controller2 you throw Exception2.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = Controller1.class)
public class ApiExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler

@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = Controller2.class)
public class ApiExceptionHandler2 extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
```

Im assuming here that your controllers are using ResponseEntity<> as a base response.

Also `assignableTypes` is an array so you can put there more than one class